# Disable multi finger touch in my Android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-sensors

In my Android application,I have a layout, in that have seven days with start and end button, each button open time picker for use choosing his favorite time. My need is have to disable multi finger touch for time picker buttons (start and end time buttons). I mean disable multi finger touch, that is if simultaneously touch two buttons that open two time picker. This is the my layout structure:

```
<LinearLayout>
  .......
  <ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout>
         <TableLayout>

            <!--Sunday -->
            <TableRow>
                <Texview/>
                <Button/>  <!-- start time -->
                <Button/>  <!-- endtime -->
            </TableRow>

              ..........                

            <!--Saturday -->
            <TableRow>
                <Texview/>
                <Button/>  <!-- start time -->
                <Button/>  <!-- endtime -->
            </TableRow>      

            .............      

         <TableLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` in every `TableRow`,`TableLayout`, and `ScrollView` and its child `LinearLayout`,but its does not disable multi touch for the start and end time buttons.  How to disable multi touch for the start and end time buttons? please assist me.

I have tried also the following:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: "have to disable multi touch for time picker buttons" -- what does this mean? What specific multi-touch gesture do you think these buttons use?

Comment: I mean disable multi finger touch, that is if simultaneously touch two buttons that open two time picker.

Answer (score 2):

So using CommonsWare answer I got to the right track in my application and here is a quick hack to *disable* multitouch.

For my app I didn't need multitouches anywhere in my app, infact they were most unwelcome. So in the `Activity` by Overriding the `dispatchTouchEvent` we get the `Action` and if it is `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` I do not pass it on. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {

    return ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

But even if you only want to disable one `View`'s `MultiTouch` then you can do so by Overriding either its `dispatchTouchEvent()`, `onInterceptTouchEvent` or `onTouchEvent()`.

**A Little Note :** Remember to pass on `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP` uninterrupted or some of your views will remain pressed state.

Answer (score 1):

There is no means for you to "disable" this, as this has nothing to do with multi-touch. Moreover, they are not simultaneous, but sequential, as both click events route through the main application thread. Hence, you are welcome to use your own business logic to decide to drop the second click event, such as:

Step #1: Have a `long lastClickTime=0L` in your activity or fragment that hosts these buttons.

Step #2: Check `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` at the top of the button's click handler (for this answer, let's assign this to a `long now` local variable). If `now-lastClickTime` is below some threshold, you ignore the click event, as it was too soon after some other click event. Otherwise, you set `lastClickTime` to be `now` and do your normal click processing.